# Cup, Cap and Kunneth: The Big Picture

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory

I've been trying to think about Kunneth Formulas and cup and cap products categorically.  It helps me to get the big picture.  Please check my understanding.

My take is, the Kunneth formula is a coproduct in the category of Cohomology rings with morphisms the cup product and Cohomology rings the objects.

Now, the cap product confuses me because if it were a morphism it would be from a ring of Cohomology and Homology products to a Homology ring.  It seems more like a functor in that case.

Comment: The cup product is just part of the structure of the objects in the category of cohomology rings (more formally, the category of graded rings). It can also be thought of as a natural transformation. The cap product is a bit more complicated; I believe it's what's called an extranatural transformation, since the functors involved are both covariant and contravariant.

Comment: What is the category of cohomology rings? Could you be a bit more precise about the categorical manner in which you would like to think about cohomology in general to give your question a bit more context?

Comment: @Tyrone OK.  I'll see if I can add a bit more this weekend.

Comment: @Tyrone Sorry, I got hit with a massive homework assignment.  I'm going to have to come back to this much later.